# java applet: Zebra printer found but command string does not print

Tags: java, applet, zebra-printers

I have a small java application that prints a label on a Zebra printer. When the port is made to an applet,  (app => applet) nothing comes out from the printer.

Any ideas why this is happening?

- The printer 'lookup' process is completed successfully from the java applet and the printer is found
- The command string to be sent is constructed properly...

but when the command is sent, nothing comes out.

Note: While the application was developed, when there was an error in the command string, nothing happened, or the printer seemed to be responding but not printing anything.

Is this a security issue? If it is, can anyone point to the right direction for solving this problem? (resources, books, tips - all welcome)

Regards,

Comment: Can you print something from the OS ? Can you put a hold on the printer and see if a Print Job is getting created ?  Can you please elaborate on how the printer is hooked up to the machine ? also what OS are you using ?

Comment: Hello, are you willing to share that code? I'm currently looking for exactly this thing. Thx, Stefan.

Comment: @Stefan I will check your site for communication details and get back 2 u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to sign your applet in order to access the local resources.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the java console and see what exception is thrown by your code.

Comment: thanks for the reply. No exceptions are thrown. Command string is OK. Don't know if it's the non-latin chars. They should not be a problem but I am just wondering...

Comment: Have you enabled trace mode in the Java Console?  Does this run in the appletviewer?

Comment: Trace mode is enabled. Haven't tried the appletviewer (will look into it).

Comment: Found the problem. Although the applet requested access to the printer it had to be singed in order to work. Maybe this is standard procedure but i thought i didn't have to sign it. Thanks for the answer + comments

Comment: How did you find out?  (and, yes, you do need to sign to get out of the sandbox)